# Using Postgres to output data from 2 tables as array

Tags: postgresql

I've got 2 tables in a Postgres DB and need some help in getting a query together to output data in a specific format if possible.

Table 1 (accounts)

```
RowID    Name    AccountNo
1        John    45356333
2        Helen   74562445
```

Table 2 (codes)

```
RowID     AccountNo    Code         Status
1         45356333     csdcwew      Active
2         45356333     gererge      Active
2         74562445     thwfewf      Active
```

I would like to be able to get the data out so I can ultimately get a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "Accounts": [
    {
      "AccountNo": "45356333",
      "Codes": [
        {
          "Code": "csdcwew",
          "Status": "Active"
        },
        {
          "Code": "gererge",
          "Status": "Active"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "AccountNo": "74562445",
      "Codes": [
        {
          "Code": "thwfewf",
          "Status": "Active"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've had a go with a query which uses the array_agg function to output all the accounts and an array of codes, but that's as far as I can get. Really, I need the status and the descriptions too.

```
 SELECT a."Name",
    array_agg(c."Codes")
   FROM ("Accounts" a
     LEFT JOIN "Codes" c ON ((c."AccountNo" = a."AccountNo")))
  GROUP BY a."Name";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close. You can continue going the way you are also aggregating the status values in the same way you aggregate the codes.  Then you would have two columns which you can iterate in order.

An alternative is that Postgres has a pretty reasonable JSON syntax which allows you to aggregate directly to JSON.

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
    'AccountNo', accountNo,
    'Codes', val ))
FROM (
    select accountNo,
        json_agg (json_build_object(
            'code', code, 
            'status', status))  as val 
        from codes
        group by accountNo) as c;
```

Comment: With a couple of tweaks for quotes for table names, this works. If I needed to get more data from the Accounts table, I didn't disclose that there are other fields on there that I'd want to include in the result, that's really my fault apologies.

Comment: Getting more details from account's table shouldn't be a problem.  You can do the same join you had in your question on `c` and then including them when the outer `json_build_object` is called.